I get a python error IndexError: Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple
veriler = list()
yazarlar = list()
kitaplar = list()
sayfalar = list()
with open('veriler.csv') as file:
     for i in file.readlines():
        veriler.append(i[:-1])
for i in veriler:
    line = i.split(',')
    yazarlar.append(line[0])
    kitaplar.append((line[1]))
    sayfalar.append((line[2]))
metin = "{:<20} {:<20} {:<4}"
    for i in range(len(yazarlar)):
        print(metin.format(yazarlar[i], kitaplar[i]), sayfalar[i])

IndexError: Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple

Your last line has a parenthesis at the wrong location. You need to pass sayfarlar[i] to metin.format along with the other two values, because your format string has three sets of curly brackets that need to be substituted. That's what the exception message is saying, the third set of brackets (index 2, since we start counting at zero) doesn't have a corresponding item in the positional arguments.
Try changing:
print(metin.format(yazarlar[i], kitaplar[i]), sayfalar[i])

To this:
print(metin.format(yazarlar[i], kitaplar[i], sayfalar[i]))


Look at your print statement, as the correct statement would be:
print(metin.format(yazarlar[i], kitaplar[i], sayfalar[i]))
